# javascript canvas intersection between two path2D

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm looking for a way to check if two path2D are intersecting but can't find a way...

Exemple :

```
// My circle
let circlePath = new Path2D();
circlePath.ellipse(x, y, radiusX, radiusY, 0, 0, Math.PI*2, false);

// My rectangle
let rectPath = new Path2D();
rectPath.rect(x, y, width, height);

// Intersect boolean
let intersect = circlePath.intersect(rectPath); // Does not exists
```

Is there a function to do that ?

I found `isPointInPath(path2D, x, y)` (that I use with my paths to check intersect with mouse) but can't use it between two paths.

Or maybe a way to get an array of all points in a Path2D to use `isPointInPath` with all points ?

Edit:

FYI, I want this for a game development, I want to be able to check collision between my entities (an entity is defined by some data and a Path2D). My entities can be squares, circles or more complex shapes.

Comment: As an aside, I would be very curious as to why you need this. Could you expand a bit more on your use case?

Comment: @Kaiido I just edited my question to explain my use case

Answer (score 2):

There currently is nothing in the API to do this.

The Path2D interface is still just an opaque object, from which we can't even extract the path-data. I actually did start working on a future proposal to expose this path-data and add a few more methods to the Path2D object, like a `getPointAtLength()`, or an export to SVG path commands, which would help doing what you want, but I wouldn't hold my breath until it's part of the API, and I must admit I didn't even consider including such a path-intersect method...

However as part of this effort I did build a prototype of that API that currently exposes only a few of the expected methods: https://github.com/Kaiido/path2D-inspection/
Among these methods there is a `toSVGString()` that can be used with [this project](https://github.com/bpmn-io/path-intersection) (that I didn't extensively test).

So we could build a `Path2D#intersects()` by merging both libraries. However note that at least mine (path2d-inspection) hasn't been extensively tested yet and I don't recommend using it in production just yet.
Anyway, here is a very quickly made hack as a proof-of-concept:

```js
const circlePath = new Path2D();
circlePath.ellipse(rand(100, 20), rand(100, 20), rand(80, 10), rand(80, 10), rand(Math.PI*2), 0, Math.PI*2, false);

// My rectangle
const rectPath = new Path2D();
rectPath.rect(rand(150), rand(100), rand(200), rand(200));

// Intersect boolean
const intersect = rectPath.intersects(circlePath);
console.log("intersect:", intersect);

// List of intersection points
const intersections = rectPath.getIntersections(circlePath);
console.log(intersections);

// Render on a canvas to verify
const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
ctx.stroke(circlePath);
ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx.stroke(rectPath);

function rand(max=1, min=0) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 50px !important }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/Kaiido/path2D-inspection@master/build/path2D-inspection.min.js"></script>
<script>
// a really quick hack to grasp 'intersect' from their esm
globalThis.module = {};
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/bpmn-io/path-intersection@master/intersect.js"></script>
<script>
// part 2 of the hack to grasp 'intersect', let's make it a Path2D method :P
{
  const intersect = module.exports;
  delete globalThis.module;
  Path2D.prototype.getIntersections = function(path2) {
    return intersect(this.toSVGString(), path2.toSVGString());
  };
  Path2D.prototype.intersects = function(path2) {
    return this.getIntersections(path2).length > 0;
  };
}
</script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I’m glad you answered this. I was trying everything to get some kind is positional data from a path2D. Looking at it in the console provides nothing but an endless tree of useless (to me) data. It interesting we have a method to determine if a single point is in path but not two paths overlapping.

Comment: @Justin well, `isPointInPath` is really necessary to do any hit testing, so it's a "basic" method, which was probably already there in most implementations for SVG. path intersection is more complex and has less obvious use cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think i will use square or circle to define my entity bound and calculate collision